# s(String) is a 'field' but is used like a 'type' C#

Tags: c#, exception

I' am trying to assign a value to a variable but i am getting that compile error: `s(String) is a 'field' but is used like a 'type'`

```
public class SForceTest
{
    String s = "";
    s = "asdsa";
 }
```

What can i do to fix that problem ? Thanks

Comment: You need to put those lines in a method or property. They can't be loose in your class.

Comment: you have to do this in a method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can only create members (and initialize them) outside of a constructor or method.  You need to place the assignment inside a constructor or method:

```
public class SForceTest
{
    String s = "";

    public SForceTest()
    {
        s = "asdsa";
    }
}
```

Comment: Why i can't make an assigment inside of a class ?

Comment: @user3864408 because the c# spec says so.  Executable code must be inside members (constructors, methods, accessors, event handlers, etc).  You can only initialize members at the class level.

Comment: Also the assignment outside of the constructor would be the same as if you would put it in the constructor. So it's actually doing s = "" and s = "asdsa" in the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

You need to either initialize it in a method, as above, or at the time of creation, e.g:

```
public class SForceTest
{
    String s = "asdsa";
}
```

You'd normally give it an accessibility modifier as well, making it look more like this (assuming we only ever want instances of this class to be able to access the field):

```
public class SForceTest
{
    private String s = "asdsa";
}
```